# Django Models Not Fetching different URLS

Tags: python, django, web-development-server

I am trying to create a music website using python django for backend. I need to fetch different spotify urls for different songs and I recommend it using my Django Admin Panel. The problem I am facing is the moment I define url for second song and the consecutive ones my songs fetch the same url I previously defined for first song. In this way, my every song dialog box plays the same song as the first one defined.

Here is the model I defined for My Song:

```
from django.db import models


class Songs(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media')

class Spot(models.Model):
    lnk = models.URLField()
```

Here are the changes I made in my HTML file to view the model:

```
                    {% for plays in play.all %}

                        <div class="col-md-3 content-grid">
                            <a class="play-icon popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog"><img src="{{plays.image.url}}" title="allbum-name"></a>

                            <a class="button play-icon popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog">{{plays.name}}</a>

                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% for links in link %}
                    <div id="small-dialog" class="mfp-hide">
                        <iframe src="{{links.lnk}}" frameborder="0"></iframe>   
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

And Finally here is the Views I am using in views.py file of app:

```
class DashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "dashboard.html"
    login_url = reverse_lazy("home")
    form = EmailSignupForm()
    play = Songs.objects.all()
    link = Spot.objects.all()
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            'form': self.form,
            'play': self.play,
            'link': self.link
        }
        login_url = reverse_lazy("home")
        return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        new_signup = Signup()
        new_signup.email = email
        new_signup.save()
        messages.info(request, "Successfully subscribed")
        login_url = reverse_lazy("home")
        return redirect("dashboard")
```

Any help would be highly aprreciated.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Here you go @Matthias